# What feats should a human rogue take to be stealthy?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, feats, rogue

I am helping a player to make a level 1 human trickster rogue in D&D 4e, but we cannot decide on a good feat. He is looking to be good at stealth both in and out of combat as well have good melee ability (planning on using a long dagger). What would be a good feat to take in order to get him to that point?

A quick overview of the rest of the party:

1. dragonborn warlord
2. dwarf druid
3. half-elf ranger
4. human sorcerer
5. the human rogue in question

Comment: FYI, it is spelled **rogue**, not **rouge**. Note the 'g' and the 'u' being one way or the other. **Rouge** is a shade of red or pink, [and a type of cosmetics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouge_%28cosmetics%29) (Though it is a very appropriate kind of colour for a rogue.)

Comment: @DoubleDragon Incidentally, formatting posts on this site is a bit more complicated than some others. See [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to how to do things like lists.

Comment: As a note, @doubleDragon, we recommend waiting a while (a day or two) to accept answers, no matter how good they are, as marking an answer as accepted tends to discourage other respondents who might have *even better* answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource you need is [Han Shot First: the Scoundrel's Guide](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3384391). It's a handbook discussing all of the rogue build options. Also, [the rules of hidden club](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2739081) are required reading. [Mr Cellophane](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3184526) has stealth specific build options.

With that said, a focus on stealth is commendable, though unnecessary.

Before we discuss increasing stealth, make sure the rogue has the cunning stalker feat. That gives him CA when he's alone. When he's not alone, he can be flanking with the warlord, druid, or ranger.

You'll want to see if anyone is interested in the teamwork benefits (particularly the druid) from silent shadows as well as the set of items in Mr. Cellophane. At level 1, this is tricky, but as he gets magic items, shadowflow armor is notable. He should buy footpads and camoflauged clothes with his starting money as non-magical stealth boosting options. Make sure he takes an appropriate background (Silent Hunter) and theme (Dead Rat Deserter, as being able to be tiny is amazing when sneaking) , especially as he won't be using a rapier.